# Change the Value of Specific Columns Based on a Condition in a DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am not sure how to automate it for specific set of columns.

It will go into a specific column, check the values. If a value is equal or larger than 10, it would replace it with 100, if it is less than that it will be 0. But then it would do that for all the columns rather than specifying the name of the column each time.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           scale = 10,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'car':X[:,0],
                                  'ball':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3': 5,
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})


df.loc[df['Feature 6'] > 10, 'Feature 6'] = 100
```

and the set of columns will be extracted using the following line

```
spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if "tu" in str(col)]
```

So basically change the values of columns containing **tu** anywhere in the column name

Comment: Why not simply try `df[df>=10]=100` and `df[df<10]=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with a `DataFrame` constructor, because it returns a 2d numpy array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df >= 10, 100, 0), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

Thank you **@Wen** for solution with [`DataFrame.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) and multiple boolean mask by `100`, `True`s are processes like `1` and `False`s like `0`:

```
df = df.ge(10).mul(100)
```

EDIT: If want applied solution only for some columns:

```
df[spike_cols]  = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df[spike_cols] >= 10, 100, 0),
                               columns=spike_cols, index=df.index)

df[spike_cols] = df[spike_cols].ge(10).mul(100)
```

Comment: you are definitely one of them.

Comment: how can I slightly edit this code so instead of changing the values of all the columns, it would be change the values of columns that contrain a specific name anywhere in the name. For example, if column contains "tu", then apply your code. A way to extract the column names is __spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if "tu" in str(col)]__

Comment: @Victor - I think need `df[spike_cols] = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df[spike_cols] >= 10, 100, 0), columns=spike_cols, index=df.index)`

Comment: @Victor - Give me a sec.